# How to set column properties when importing CSV file using PowerPivot

Tags: csv, powerpivot

I am using PowerPivot to import a large csv file (just under 2 million rows).  The file only has 4 columns, one of which is a number.  Some of the numbers in this column have decimal places.  However, when PowerPivot imports the csv, it strips out all values after the decimal point.  I can add decimal places after the import but it's lost the values at this point.

When importing the CSV, there appears to be no options to set the column value before the data is imported.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Consider using Power Query (Get and Transform) to load the data and define the data type of the column. You can load the query results to the data model, so you can access it with Power Pivot. Power Query and Power Pivot complement each other. Power Query has a lot of functionality to clean up and sort out data before Power Pivot does the analysis.